# Replace special characters in variable in awk shell command

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I am currently executing the following command:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="," ; getline ; H=$0 } N != $3 { N=$3 ; print H > "/Directory/FILE_"$3"_DOWNLOAD.csv" } { print > "/Directory/FILE_"$3"_DOWNLOAD.csv" }' /Directory/FILE_ALL_DOWNLOAD.csv
```

This takes the value from the third position in the CSV file and creates a CSV for each distinct $3 value. Works as desired.

The input file looks as follows:

```
Name, Amount, ID
"ABC", "100.00", "0000001"
"DEF", "50.00", "0000001"
"GHI", "25.00", "0000002"
```

Unfortunately I have no control over the value in the source (CSV) sheet, the $3 value, but I would like to eliminate special (non-alphanumeric) characters from it. I tried the following to accomplish this but failed...

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="," ; getline ; H=$0 } N != $3 { N=$3 ; name=${$3//[^a-zA-Z_0-9]/}; print H > "/Directory/FILE_"$name"_DOWNLOAD.csv" } { print > "/Directory/FILE_"$name"_DOWNLOAD.csv" }' /Directory/FILE_ALL_DOWNLOAD.csv
```

Suggestions? I'm hoping to do this in a single command but if anyone has a bash script answer that would work.

Comment: Example record from source file: " 123.", "Company Name" " 456." produces a file /Directory/FILE_" 456."_DOWNLOAD.csv - I am looking to get /Directory/FILE_456_DOWNLOAD.csv -- Thanks.

Comment: It would be useful to edit your question and add a few lines from your file.

Comment: I'm curious - where did you get the idea for the syntax `name=${$3//[^a-zA-Z_0-9]/}`?

Comment: @Ed looks like a hybrid of bash substitution on an awk field to me.

Comment: Oh, I see - if this was bash and $3 was a bash variable.... Got it, thx.

Comment: Is there supposed to be a comma in between "Company Name" and " 456." in example you have left in the comment? Either way, could you post a sample of your input in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely not a job you should be using `getline` for, see http://awk.info/?tip/getline

It looks like you just want to reproduce the first line of your input file in every $3-named file. That'd be:

```
awk -F, '
NR==1 { hdr=$0; next }
$3 != prev { prev=name=$3; gsub(/[^[:alnum:]_]/,"",name); $0 = hdr "\n" $0 }
{ print > ("/Directory/FILE_" name "_DOWNLOAD.csv") }
' /Directory/FILE_ALL_DOWNLOAD.csv
```

Note that you must always parenthesize expressions on the right side of output redirection (`>`) as it's ambiguous otherwise and different awks will behave differently if you don't.

Feel free to put it all back onto one line if you prefer.

Comment: +1 Ah yes, `[:alnum:]` was what I was looking for - for some reason I was trying it with two `[[ ]]` on each side so it wasn't working.

Comment: Could you not have just used an associative array instead of prev ?Actually from OPs description `creates a CSV for each distinct $3 value` is a comparison even necessary ?

Comment: The comparison to `prev` here is to only prefix `hdr` in each file once (well once per-run of `$3` values but that's per-OP specification).

Answer (score 1):

If you always expect the number to be in the last field of your CSV and you know that each field is wrapped in quotes, you could use this awk to extract the value `456` from the input you have provided in the comment:

```
echo " 123.", "Company Name" " 456." | awk -F'[^a-zA-Z0-9]+' 'NF { print $(NF-1) }'
```

This defines the field separator as any number of non-alphanumeric characters and retrieves the second-last field.

If this is sufficient to reliably retrieve the value, you could construct your filename like this:

```
file = "/Directory/FILE_" $(NF-1) "_DOWNLOAD.csv"
```

and output to it as you're already doing.

Answer (score 0):

`bash` variable expansions do not occur in single quotes.

They also cannot be performed on `awk` variables.

That being said you don't need that to work.

`awk` has string manipulation functions that can perform the same tasks. In this instance you likely want the `gsub` function.

Comment: Looks like a comment to me!

Comment: @TomFenech I originally wrote it as a comment and then realized that it actually answers the question of "how to normalize the field data" that is being asked.

Answer (score 0):

Would this not work for what you asked ?

```
awk -F, 'a=NR==1{x=$0;next}
!a{gsub(/[^[:alnum:]]/,"",$3);print x"\n"$0 >> "/Directory/FILE_"$3"_DOWNLOAD.csv"}' file
```

Comment: Question answered by another question! `;)`